# How do I create a cycle graph with igraph?

Tags: python, r, igraph

How do I create a cycle graph on `n` nodes with *igraph*, either in R or Python?

It should look like this, but for an arbitrary number of nodes:

[image]

---

EDIT: Since it was requested that I should add a code attempt, here's one possibility in R that I found to be too complicated:

```
n <- 5 
make_graph( c(tail(rep(1:n, each=2), -1), 1) )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for python you need to install:

```
pip install python-igraph
pip install pycairo
```

Then you can use `Graph.Ring` from `igraph` like below:

```
import igraph as ig
nodes = 5
g = ig.Graph.Ring(n=nodes, circular=True)
ig.plot(g,vertex_label = range(1,nodes+1))
```

In R, the relevant igraph function is [`make_ring()`](https://igraph.org/r/doc/make_ring.html). You can read in Doc:

> Create a ring graph
> Description
> A ring is a one-dimensional lattice and this function is a special case of make_lattice.

> Usage
> make_ring(n, directed = FALSE, mutual = FALSE, circular = TRUE)

---

Output:
[image]

Comment: Excellent! I'd be curious about how you found `Graph.Ring`.  Google? Documentation search?

Comment: @Szabolcs welcome dude, I read [here](https://igraph.org/python/doc/tutorial/generation.html#lattice), I don't know before

Comment: @Szabolcs thanks for your edit, I add some details, read and if you want edit them, this is your question and your answer, this is your area ;)

Answer (score 2):

Try `make_ring` if you are using `igraph` with `R`

```
plot(make_ring(5))
```

[image]

Comment: Can you let me know with what search terms you found this function? Or you already knew about it before?

Comment: @Szabolcs I already know it before by reading https://igraph.org/r/html/latest/ many times.

Answer (score 1):

In R with `n` vertices:

```
n <- 8

seq_len(n) %>%
  {c(head(., -1), tail(., -1))} %>%
  matrix(ncol = 2) %>%
  rbind(c(n, 1)) %>%
  graph_from_edgelist(directed = FALSE)
```

Comment: This works very well, I could wrap it up into a function, and it easily generalizes to the directed case. However, I wonder if you are aware of a simpler solution.

Comment: Isn't this simple enough? If you want you can put it in 1 command (I like to use pipe): `graph_from_edgelist(matrix(c(seq_len(n), c(2:n, 1)), ncol = 2), directed = FALSE)`